# using a same column in place of another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which have 3 fields: `id, name, reporting` to which have other ids:

```
ID    NAME   REPORT
-------------------
1     asd     3
2     vv      1
3     dv      2
```

I want name to be printed in place of ids in the report column:

```
ID    NAME   REPORT
-------------------
1     asd    dv
2     vv     asd
3     dv     vv
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join on to the table that contains your report names using the report id.

Something like this:

```
Select a.Id,
       a.Name,
        b.Name as Report

From dbo.myTable a
Join dbo.myTable b on a.Report = b.Id
```

I should add that if some `Names` don't have a corresponding report id then you may want to use a `Left Join` instead of a `Join` so that you still get all rows in the base table.

e.g

```
Select a.Id,
       a.Name,
        IsNull(b.Name, 'No Report Defined') as Report

From dbo.myTable a
Left Join dbo.myTable b on a.Report = b.Id
```

Comment: It looks like it is the same table that contains the names :)

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo - Thanks for pointing that out - how strange.  Anyway, I have amended my answer. Thanks again, Barry

Comment: @Jasmeet - I have amended my answer to reflect this.